# Containing illegal charaters in select aliases "as"

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I am using pivot function in SQL Server.

My select is built dynamically and uses pivot function.

Since the are a lot of guid in the values I use "as" and assign it a name -  (it would be easy to maintain it if I give the columns that are generated from attribute values new names.)

But the values include `.`, space, `-`, `+` and other illegal characters. Is there a way to contain those characters?

Here is a simple example :

```
string s = 
" select MyColumn as My Attribute
  from MyTable My Table "
```

where `My Attribute` and `My Table` are generated names

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Enclose those names in square brackets:

```
string s = 
" SELECT MyColumn AS [My Attribute]
  FROM MyTable [My Table] "
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use [Delimited Identifiers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa224033%28v=sql.80%29.aspx), which use either `""` or `[]` to contain (almost) arbitrary character sequences:

> An identifier that complies with all the rules for the format of identifiers can be used with or without delimiters. An identifier that does not comply with the rules for the format of regular identifiers must always be delimited.

Whether `""` works depends on the `QUOTED_IDENTIFIERS` setting of your session. `[]` may always be used.